# oracle left join query for paging

Tags: sql, oracle, paging

```
select rownum rnum, * from group g 
  left join user u on u.group_id = g.id 
  where rnum between 1, 2
  order by g.created_at desc;
```

Suppose newest group1, group2 have 2 users each.

Then above query will return 2 records of group1.

I would like to set rownum based by group records so I can have group1 and group2(ie: above query should return 4 records).

I tried dense_rank() but I must order the records by group_id not created_at.

Can anyone give me the query for this?

Comment: How's MySQL involved here? Also, if you add some sample table data and expected output, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Do you not care WHICH 2 records of group are chosen - you just want any 2?

Comment: Your query is wrong, the use of ROWNUM is logically incorrect. You need to use a simple pagination query.

Comment: The problem is that I am joining two tables. I need a distinct(by GROUP.ID) rownumber for correct pagination.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select rownum rnum, * from group g 
>   left join user u on u.group_id = g.id 
>   where rnum between 1, 2
>   order by g.created_at desc;
> ```

Your query is **syntactically and logically incorrect**.

If you are looking for a **PAGINATION** query, then you need to first understand how **ROWNUM** works.

For example,

I have following employee table.

```
SQL> SELECT empno, sal FROM emp ORDER BY sal DESC;

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7839       5000
      7902       3000
      7788       3000
      7566       2975
      7698       2850
      7782       2450
      7499       1600
      7844       1500
      7934       1300
      7521       1250
      7654       1250
      7876       1100
      7900        950
      7369        800

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**I need the 5th, 6th, 7th and 8th highest salaried employees**:

```
SQL> SELECT empno, sal
  2  FROM   (SELECT empno, sal, ROWNUM AS rnum
  3          FROM   (SELECT empno, sal
  4                  FROM   emp
  5                  ORDER BY sal DESC
  6                 )
  7          WHERE rownum <= 8)
  8  WHERE  rnum >= 5;

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7698       2850
      7782       2450
      7499       1600
      7844       1500

SQL>
```

You could use other ways of pagination. If you are on **12c**, you could use the new **Top-N row limiting** feature. Look at the link http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php#paging for more details.

Comment: The problem is that I am joining two tables. I need a distinct(by GROUP.ID) rownumber for correct pagination.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried dense_rank() but I must order the records by group_id not
>   created_at.

And this was good idea:

```
select id, name, created_at, usid
  from (
    select dense_rank() over (order by created_at desc) rnk, 
        g.id, g.name, g.created_at, u.id usid
      from groups g left join users u on u.group_id = g.id)
  where rnk < 3 order by id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a5f7/1)

Results (I added one more group to show, that only newest are selected):

```
        ID NAME       CREATED_AT  USID
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
         2 Group2     2015-01-09  Kyle
         2 Group2     2015-01-09  Eric
         3 Group3     2015-01-12  Kenny
         3 Group3     2015-01-12  Butters
```

---

Alternatively you can use:

```
select g.id, name, created_at, u.id usid
  from (
    select * from (
        select * from groups order by created_at desc) 
      where rownum < 3 ) g
  left join users u on g.id = u.group_id
  order by g.id
```

Comment: dense_rank() rank by created_at. But I need to rank by Group.ID. The second query has problems if I am using where condition.

Comment: I don't catch it. And as I see - other answerers too. Query just shows two most recently created groups and their members. Maybe you want `dense_rank() over (order by g.ID desc)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `row_number()` with the `partition by` clause:

```
select id, name, created_at, usid
from (select row_number() over (partition by g.id order by created_at desc) as seqnum, 
             g.id, g.name, created_at, u.id as usid
      from groups g left join
           users u
           on u.group_id = g.id
     ) ug
where seqnum <= 2
order by id;
```